# How to find eigenvectors and eigenvalues for a matrix whose entry a_ij is given by ij

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Could someone please help me with this question:

Let A be the n×n matrix whose elements are given by a_ij = ij. Find its eigenvalues
and its eigenvectors.

The only way I can think of is taking the determinant of A-labda*I, but this seems like very tedious work. Then I thought I should first apply Gauss-Jordan elimination, but I'm really stuck on how to do that here. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Ps. Is there a name for this kind of matrix? If there is, that would be helpful for googling!

Comment: Make some computations and the answer will present itself.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm stuck at what computations...

Comment: sorry, I would rather not elaborate. Do your homework by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

if the matrix $A_{2\times2}$ has elements $a_{ij}=ij$, then:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{1\cdot1} & {1\cdot2} \\ {2\cdot1} & {2\cdot2}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

Note: since $a_{ij} = ij = ji ) a_{ji}$, the matrix is symmetric, i.e $A^\intercal = A.$